# how to add an integer to the end of a Intlist using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

```
public IntNode first;

public class IntNode{
    public int item;
    public IntNode next;

    public IntNode(int i, IntNode n) {
        item = i;
        next = n;
    }
public void addLast(int x) {
    IntNode p = first;
    while (p.next!=null) {
        p = p.next;
    }
    p.next = new IntNode(x,null);

}
```

So I want to add an integer x to the end of the IntNode, and I did it iteratively. How to do it using recursion?

Comment: Hint: You need a second parameter in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this piece of code with your last method.

```
public void addLast(int x, IntNode p) {
    if(p.next!=null)
    {
        p.addLast(x, p.next);
    }
    else
    {
       p.next = new IntNode(x,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: That helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If worked, you can choose my answer as the answer and vote to it. I really can use some extra points here.